# Better jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

Let me be clear this line of code works right now. I just feel like its written stupid. Do you know a cleaner way to write this:

```
 $('#'+this.wrapper.id+' .nub').foo();
```

I ran the answers through jspref.com and here are the results:
http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-context-test

Looks like `.find` is the winner. Atleast in chrome.

Comment: people who downvote and don't comment are worse than hitler, worse I say!

Comment: I have gotten some great and very valid answers already guys, come on with all the downvotes. There is nothing illegitimate about wanting to write your code better, even in trivial cases.

Comment: This is not a bad question, you are correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it could be argued that this question would be better placed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 for valid criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(this.wrapper).find('.nub').bar();
```

Comment: Best answer according to benchmark. And you did answer make the suggestion before xdazz

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.nub', this.wrapper).foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `this.wrapper` as the context of the selector.

```
$('.nub', this.wrapper).foo();
```

or

```
$(this.wrapper).find('.nub').foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually that bad. If you wanted, you could put the selector string into its own variable, though:

```
var selectorString = "#" + this.wrapper.id + " .nub";
$(selectorString).foo();
```

Comment: meh, thats basically the same. Really I already have part of the selection as a dom element, should be able to leverage that somehow.

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Well, there's not much to improve upon. It's only only line of code. To be honest, I don't think there's anything wrong with your current solution.

Comment: Nah, I want to know the best way to do this E-V-E-R! Its just one line, but I will have to use a similar selector often. Its worth knowing the right way.

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Actually, I would consider your current solution the best way to do it. There are other ways, of course, and any of them could be argued to be the best. I believe your way would be the fastest, though.